# Accessing sqllite db from a thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-sqlite

Have set up a storage adapter (Contextual) for help creating and managing a single database and table. Trying to access the table from a new thread for reading records and transmitting them via HTTP in the background. Other access to the database is activity based and insert only. Although the data is small the thread may run a few seconds based on the number of possible records. There is not need to communicate back to the UI.

**StorageAdapter Class (SQL Lite Set up)**

```
private static SQLiteDatabase db;
private Context context;
private StorageOpenHelper dbHelper;

public StorageAdapter(Context _context) {
  this.context = _context;
  dbHelper = new StorageOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

The error message from the thread below is: "The constructor StorageAdapter(Worker) is undefined"

Here is the thread:

```
public void run () {
  // Does Storage Adapter need to be runnable           
  // Read DB ID's of committed (1) records into array
  **StorageAdapter storageAdapter = new StorageAdapter(this);**
  storageAdapter.open();
  cursor = storageAdapter.queueCommID();
  int i = 0;
  int currcnt = cursor.getCount();
  if (cursor.getPosition() == -1) cursor.moveToFirst();
  while (i < currcnt) {
    // Send single record to server
    sendrec(cursor);
i=i+1;
cursor.moveToNext();
  }
  storageAdapter.close();
  stop();
};
```

Sure hope I did not confuse everyone. Been chasing my tail for a few days and I am very confused.Thank yo for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like you are creating your StorageAdapter instance from within a Worker instance. that means the **this** references a Worker instead of a Context. in case your Worker is an anonymous class, you could use something like **MyActivity.this** instead of just **this**.

Comment: Chased that one as well with no positive outcome. Still unable to create an instance of the storage adapter to query the table and get a cursor back from the storage adapter.

Comment: so are you passing a context to the StorageAdapter constructor now? what is the error than?

Comment: I am now. Moved the thread back to the activity which passes the context to the StorageAdapter. There is no error now, but would like to have the thread running outside the activity. Need to work on it. Thank you, your questions provoked a solution for me. If you have an answer to making the Storage adapter a thread, that would be awesome.

Comment: just move it to it's own file and pass the context as a parameter for it's constructor - new MyAsyncTast(context) or new MyAsyncTast(this) from within any activity since activity inherits from context.